How to get rid off jellyfin which was installed via flatpak
I installed jellyfin via flatpak but decided it's not for me so I removed it using the flatpak uninstall command.
Next I installed embyserver again from flatpak but every time I start embyserver which uses the same port as jellyfin the jellyfin server responds on port 8096.
How do I get rid of jellyfin when flatpak no longer sees it as installed?

On a hunch I deleted my browser cache for the last couple of hours and sure enough that resolved the issue.
So I'm answering my question just in case some other frustrated penguin comes along with the same issue.
